# Efficient and accurate conversion of currency type to integer

Tags: delphi, precision, type-conversion

If possible, I would like to avoid converting a `Currency` to `Extended` (and possible losing precision) in code similar to the following:

```
function CurrencyToNumeric(aCurrency: Currency; aScale: Integer): Int64;
const 
  scales: array [-{18}5..-1] of int64 = (100000, 10000, 1000, 100, 10); 
var
  aCurrencyAsInt64: Int64 absolute aCurrency;
begin
  if aScale = -4 then
    Result := aCurrencyAsInt64
  else
    Result := Round(aCurrency * scales[aScale]); // currency -> extended -> integer
end;
```

Is that possible?

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Comment: When you use Round there is precision losing (pretty much by definition) and that dwarfs any possible rounding error with multiplication.

Comment: @Dsm If the multiply takes you just the wrong side of `x.5` then that might not be the case. I don't think it can happen here, but I also don't think it is trivial to prove.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, yes I suppose. Of course it is the division by 10000 that could cause the issue, not really the multiplication, but your solution addresses that.

Comment: This looks like severe case of over-engineering for me, esp. scaling beyond `Currency` precision and loop during conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for a function like this:

```
function CurrencyToNumeric(aCurrency: Currency; aScale: Integer): int64;
var
  aCurrencyAsInt64: int64 absolute aCurrency;
  i, factor, rem: Integer;
begin
  if aScale <= -4 then begin
    factor := 1;
    for i := -4 downto aScale+1 do begin
      factor := factor * 10;
    end;
    Result := aCurrencyAsInt64 * factor;
  end else begin
    factor := 1;
    for i := -4 to aScale-1 do begin
      factor := factor * 10;
    end;
    Result := aCurrencyAsInt64 div factor;
    rem := aCurrencyAsInt64 mod factor;
    if rem>=factor div 2 then begin
      inc(Result);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

This part of the code

```
if rem>=factor div 2 then begin
  inc(Result);
end;
```

implements the rounding policy. You may very well wish to make a different choice. Modify this code to do so, it should be obvious how to go about that.

However, I am also not convinced that the version in the question is broken. Do you have any example input where it fails? On the other hand, avoiding converting to binary floating point for a fixed point decimal type does feel sensible. Now, if only Embarcadero had implemented this darn type without resorting to using floating point operations.

Comment: It seemed to me that such a thing is possible, but I have no such example. It is entirely possible that I went a little too far in trying to eradicate some implicit type conversions.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to David's answer, I ended up with following implementation, which is not only float-free but also faster than function from the question.

```
function CurrencyToNumeric(Value: Currency; Scale: Integer): Int64;
const
  factors: array [-4..-1] of Int64 = (10000, 1000, 100, 10);
var
  factor: Integer;
  ValueAsInt64: Int64 absolute Value;
begin
  if Scale = -4 then
    Result := ValueAsInt64
  else if Scale < -4 then
    Result := ValueAsInt64 * factors[4 + Scale]
  else begin
    factor := factors[-(4 + Scale)];
    Result := ValueAsInt64 div factor;
    if ValueAsInt64 mod factor >= factor div 2 then Inc(Result);
  end;
end;
```